# option not getting selected automatically

Tags: shell, ksh

I am writing a sell script to automate some steps for server , first i have to switch user then server gives me areas to select then i have to select 1 for  area and then i have to run a  perl program lmsyscon which give me four option then i have to select 3 . then it again gives me 2 option and i have to select 2nd by deafult .here is my script

```
su poletst -c ". /try/lamtst/.profile Test"
expect -c 'spawn lmsyscon; send 3\r"; interact'
expect -c 'send "1\r"; interact'
```

the problem is last line is not executing and it is not selecting 2 by default

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... This is too complicated. Besides, your `su` command has no effect on following `expect` invocations (those are run as your current user).

Instead, create an `expect` script that does all 3 steps: changes the user and runs stuff. This is easier.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do so?